# How to send an email after pressing a button with php?

Tags: php, email, button, send

I have xampp installed with apache and mercury. I have configured mercury so I can send emails from my scripts, and I have tested it and successfully managed to send some emails to my email address.

I want to send an email after I press a button, but the following script isn't working. Can you please tell me what can I do or what is wrong with the code?

Thanx !

Code for sample.php:

```
<form action="sample.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Send details" />
    <input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="1" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))
{
    $to      = 'example@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = '';
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo 'Email Sent.';
}

?>
```

Comment: It works for me. You don't have a `From:` header; maybe your e-mail infrastructure doesn't like that and refuses to deliver.

Comment: Obligatory reading: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: @Theraot As I said, I can send mails from mercury's interface but I don't know what's the problem with the code or what should I do. I have followed the steps from here https://www.zoe.vc/2008/mercury-mail-transport-system-fur-externe-mail-konfigurieren/ with gmail as SMTP. Should I do something more?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

Comment: @user1365013 why haven't you posted [PHP official](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) documentation to the function, instad of using untrusted website, which has **a lot** of misleading information in their "documentations"?

Comment: @haynar I have to integrate that function into a php script of a friend

Comment: ok, but how does it relate to my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing locally you need to set some settings in order to use SMTP.

This might help: http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I haven't went into the depths of Mercury, because I took the PHPMailer route a long ago.

Still I can tell you that Gmail is very picky, it requires encryptation that I don't know if the mail function provides.

Aside from that it may ban your mail server, for example using smtpd it will allow me send mails for a while until they silently stop working (I guess their verificatiosn take a while).

It doesn't stop there yet, for example it may decide that the behaviour of your app is susupicious and will stop allowing it to send mail until you log in from the same mahcine via web.

And if you have two factor authentication enabled... well you code can't (or atleast shouldn't) access your cellphone, you will have to log in with some frequency to keep it working.

Of course there is a ways to solve this problems, first you should go to the [Connected Sites, Apps, and Services](https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens) page, and there create an `Application-specific password` that your app should use to authenticate. Afterwards go to the [Allow a new application to access your account](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) page and it will give you a time to log in with the app. You can read more about at [google's support](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833) page.

All in all, I have two recommendations:

- Use PHPMailer
- No longer use GMail, i've recently started using [mail.com](http://www.mail.com/int/) for mail from applications.